# How do contact type tachometers work?

Tags: tachometer

In case of contact type tachometers we put the tip into a small hole in the rotating body. Sometimes there is a disc in the tachometer shaft that we touch with the surface of the rotating body. What is the science and logic behind this?
The picture attached below elaborates it.

Type1

[image: Type-:1]

Type2

[image: Type:-2]

Comment: What tip?  What hole? What rotating body? We can't read your mind.

Comment: This seems like a question already adequately answered on the web, for example [Wikipedia Tachometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachometer), or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tachometer measures the rate of rotation of its shaft. Common technologies for doing this are magnetic or optical. Both of these methods produce pulses at a frequency proportional to the rotation rate.In the magnetic type, pole pieces induce pulses in a coil. In the optical type there is a disk with fingers or lines which cause the light received by an opto transistor (or diode) to vary as the disk rotates. If the shaft of the tachometer is held against the end of the rotating shaft, then the tachometer will rotate at the same speed at the shaft being measured. If there is a disk on the tachometer shaft and the outside of this disk is held against the outside of the rotating body then the tachometer will rotate at a speed of V * Cb / Ct, where V is the rotational velocity of the rotating body, Cb is the circumference of the rotating body and Ct is the circumference of the disk on the tachometer, therefore the reading on the tachometer will have to be multiplied by Ct / Cb to obtain the speed of the rotating body.

Answer (score 0):

No great science.  Inside the device is a generator whose output voltage is a function of its rotor speed.  Since the rotor is mechanically connected to the motor under test, the electronics in the device converts the voltage to an rpm reading of the motor speed. The disc attachment allows a measurement of surface speed per minute.

Comment: Are you sure they work that way? I've never looked at one but it seems like an odd way to go about it, the first thing that would come to mind if I was designing one would be to use an optical encoder or hall effect sensor and measure the frequency.

Comment: @PeterJ There were tachometers made this way. There are even purely [mechanical tachometers](http://www.checkline.com/product/HTM). Modern digital contact tachometers mostly don't use this principle.

Answer (score 0):

There is an encoder (optical or magnetic) inside the instrument that provides pulses for each revolution of the probe. The microcontroller inside the instrument times the pulses and calculates the RPM and displays it.